# Android Seekbar thumb position in pixel

Tags: android, seekbar

How can I get current position of thumb in pixel for SeekBar?

Currently I am trying to get the position on the bases of calculation.

Screen width, Seek Bar width, current seek progress and all. But I am not able to get exact position out of it.

Do any one have any idea?

---

Coding for same is as below.

I want to drow one component on top of SeekBar thumb.

```
translation = calculateTranslation(this.deviceScreenWidth, seekBarWidth, seekBar1T.getMax(), Integer.valueOf(ConstantData.seekbar_fifth.toString()), topComponentWidth, 0);
        if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(translation - 1,
                    translation, 0, 0);
            anim.setFillAfter(true);
            anim.setDuration(0);
            edtTextRodUpDown.startAnimation(anim);  
        }else{
            edtTextRodUpDown.setTranslationX(translation);
        }
```

and calculate Translation like

```
    private float calculateTranslation(int screenWidth, int seekBarWidth, int seekMaxProgress, int currentProgress, int componentWidth, int extraDifference){
    double calculatedPosition = 0f;
    calculatedPosition = (double)((double)(seekBarWidth-((screenWidth-seekBarWidth))) / (double)seekMaxProgress) * (double)currentProgress;
    calculatedPosition = calculatedPosition - (double)(componentWidth/2);
    calculatedPosition = calculatedPosition + extraDifference;
    Double d = new Double(calculatedPosition);
    if(d < 0){
        return 0.0f;
    }else if(d + componentWidth > screenWidth){
        return screenWidth-componentWidth;
    }else{
        return d.floatValue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26):

I did this:

```
int width = seekBar.getWidth()
            - seekBar.getPaddingLeft()
            - seekBar.getPaddingRight();
int thumbPos = seekBar.getPaddingLeft()
            + width
            * seekBar.getProgress()
            / seekBar.getMax();
```

Comment: How to get this in vertical seekbar

Comment: @NaveenKumarM Just use getHeight, getPaddingBottom, and getPaddingTop instead. I don't see why this wouldn't work...

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `getBounds()` to get this info.

This sample code below is for instance aligning a `TextView` with the `seekbar` thumb position.

```
TextView sliderIndicator = ...
Rect bounds = seekBar.getThumb().getBounds();
sliderIndicator.setTranslationX(seekBar.getLeft() + bounds.left);
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution! This is the way to go imo, seems to be reliable and smooth

Comment: this is a perfect solution. no need for third party libraries, just this would do the trick

Answer (score 2):

The seekbar thumb has a thumb offset, which is basically a slight shift to the right. So you have to make sure that you take this into account as well:

```
int thumbPos = seekbar.getMeasuredWidth() * seekbar.getProgress() / seekbar.getMax() - seekbar.getThumbOffset();
```

Comment: As I understood, `getThumbOffset()` calculates a width of the thumb, so, don't subtract it from position.